# What is the most common stateless way for authentication in microservices?

Tags: design, architecture, programming-practices, microservices, authentication

I'm trying to get into Microservices by creating a project, so far I've stumbled upon authentication mechanisms, in a monolithic architecture, the client (web app) would send a request with the user credentials to receive a JWT and send it in every upcoming request. However, when it comes to Microservices I found out that there were two different ways to achieve the same, stateless authentication mechanism, either by delegating the authentication and authorization responsibilities to the gateway service, or by using OAuth2 (or OpenID Connect??). Most online resources recommend OAuth2, however isn't it used for service-to-service authorization? Should I use the authorization code flow with password grant?

The API is only going to be accessed by a single client (web app), so no other service is going to ask the user for their data consent or something.

Comment: In a microservice environment, there are 2 authentications in play: 1. The authentication of the user accessing the system 2. The authentication of the microservices among themselves. Which of those two are you referring to in your question?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I'm trying to implement the authentication of the user, which is why I'm not sure if OAuth is optimal in this case.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I think it is the first as he is referring to the client as a web app. I assume he means a front end. I know that the whole thing is technically a web app but I doubt that it is talking to itself. XD  I voted your comment because I wasnt sure either.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** This answer is not relevant to the question due to confusion about the use case.  I am leaving it for now in case it's helpful to anyone else.

I don't know if it's the most common but this is a perfect use case for using [client-certificates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/ba-p/324623).  This is also referred to as [mutual authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) (mTLS)

Part of what makes this appealing in this kind of situation is that you likely are already managing a certificate on the client (the web-server.)  If you aren't then you should fix that first.  The only difference between a server-certificate and a client-certificate is that the latter is signed to allow it to be used for client authentication.  This means that one certificate can be used for both its server-authentication and its client-authentication.  You just need it signed for both capabilities.

mTLS is built into the TLS standard and generally requires no additional libraries.  If a request can't produce an acceptable cert, they are stopped before they get an opportunity
to poke at any part of your web API.  The biggest challenge tends to be figuring out how to make your host accept them and pass the identity details (e.g. subject) to the auth module of your framework.  One fairly simple approach is to let a reverse-proxy do this and pass these details along on a header.  Just make sure you clear anything that a client (attacker) might try to pass in on that header or headers.

Comment: Makes sense, however is client certificate authentication stateless? Isn't the use of web tokens when it comes to stateless authentication more efficient?

Comment: I don't see how going out to a third server to get a key is going to be more efficient than using a local certificate.  As far as stateless goes, it's part of the TLS connection.  It's part of the handshake.  Can you explain a little more what you think would be the problem?

Comment: I may have not understood client certificate authentication properly, but isn't it based on certificates exchange instead of username & password validation? Wouldn't It require every application user (the actual end user) to own a local certificate that would be sent in every request?

Comment: This question's most liked answer explains why JWTs are recommended when compared to client certificate https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128185/jwt-vs-client-certificates

Comment: Your question says "The API is only going to be accessed by a single client (web app)" and you mention server-to-server authentication.  What is your use case exactly?

Comment: Also, I don't think you understand the linked answer.  JWTs can be intercepted and used in replay attacks.  The fact that they expire is a requirement because of that.  PKI schemes are not subject to this.  The private key must be leaked.  While that's possible, if you store the key properly, the client machine would have to be compromised and it's game over anyway, if we are talking about server-to-server interactions.  There's also nothing stopping you from expiring your certs daily, hourly, whatever you think is right.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, end users will use a javascript single page app from the browser, and authenticate by entering their username and password, just as most web apps do. My issue is that I am not sure whether I should use OAuth2 (or OIDC) or the usual authentication from a gateway service (which handles the generation and verification of JWTs).

Comment: I see, so client authentication is optimal for server-to-server interactions, and not user-to-server. Sorry for the confusion again.

Comment: That's not my area of expertise but I think in general, having a third party identity broker is the way things are going.  Usernames and passwords are going the way of the dodo because they are fundamentally broken.  Here's an article for more: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/passwords-only-obsolete-useless-michael-mcloughlin-

Comment: Also, you might want to read this article referenced in the comments of that answer: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/09/28/attacking-jwt-authentication/